# JS | Why is the property of the Object truthy although it's empty?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

So the value of the first object with the property "single" is empty, but still truthy, what did I wrong?

```
 function every(collection, pre) {
  var rtr = null;

  for(var e in collection){
     if(collection[e][pre] !== null && 
        collection[e][pre] !== undefined && 
        collection[e][pre] !== 0 && 
        collection[e][pre] !== "" && 
        collection[e][pre] !== false && 
        collection[e][pre] !== NaN){

       rtr = true;
     }
     else 
        rtr = false;
  }

  console.log(rtr);

}

every([{"single": ""}, {"single": "double"}], "single");
```

Answer (score 1):

You `console.log` outside the loop. Try this (I also removed the stray `):

```
function every(collection, pre) {
  var rtr = null;

  for(var e in collection){
     if(collection[e][pre] !== null && 
        collection[e][pre] !== undefined && 
        collection[e][pre] !== 0 && 
        collection[e][pre] !== "" && 
        collection[e][pre] !== false && 
        collection[e][pre] !== NaN){

       rtr = true;
     }
     else 
        rtr = false;

     console.log(rtr);
  }

}

every([{"single": ""}, {"single": "double"}], "single");
```

It logs

```
false
true
```